# Is there a way to quickly turn text to an array in python in vscode?

Tags: python, arrays, visual-studio-code, hash

I have a long list (~5000) of hash digest, the list looks like this:

```
F5CA38F748A1D6EAF726B8A42FB575C3C71F1864A8143301782DE13DA2D9202B
6F4B6612125FB3A0DAECD2799DFD6C9C299424FD920F9B308110A2C1FBD8F443
785F3EC7EB32F30B90CD0FCF3657D388B5FF4297F2F9716FF66E9B69C05DDD09
535FA30D7E25DD8A49F1536779734EC8286108D115DA5045D77F3B4185D8F790
C2356069E9D1E79CA924378153CFBBFB4D4416B1F99D41A2940BFDB66C5319DB
B7A56873CD771F2C446D369B649430B65A756BA278FF97EC81BB6F55B2E73569
5F9C4AB08CAC7457E9111A30E4664920607EA2C115A1433D7BE98E97E64244CA
...
```

Is there a fast way to turn this into an array? Kind of like this:

```
Array = [F5CA38F748A1D6EAF726B8A42FB575C3C71F1864A8143301782DE13DA2D9202B,
         6F4B6612125FB3A0DAECD2799DFD6C9C299424FD920F9B308110A2C1FBD8F443,
         785F3EC7EB32F30B90CD0FCF3657D388B5FF4297F2F9716FF66E9B69C05DDD09,
         535FA30D7E25DD8A49F1536779734EC8286108D115DA5045D77F3B4185D8F790,
         C2356069E9D1E79CA924378153CFBBFB4D4416B1F99D41A2940BFDB66C5319DB,
         B7A56873CD771F2C446D369B649430B65A756BA278FF97EC81BB6F55B2E73569,
         5F9C4AB08CAC7457E9111A30E4664920607EA2C115A1433D7BE98E97E64244CA,
         ...]
```

I am using vscode.

Comment: You should check out the [shortcuts in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference). You probably don't need python for this. Just select everything, insert cursor at end of each line selected (⇧⌥I), and type a comma. Then you just need `[` and `]` at the ends. Once you know these shortcuts in vs-code, these kind of things only take a couple seconds.

Comment: Put in text file, read it in a list, then print it console and copy it ?

Comment: I was thinking about doing something like this, but I am worried the console won't be able to display all of it

Answer (score 2):

You can use str.split() to split a string into a list. If you load the string in and want every character to be an element, split with an empty string. `string_name.split('')`. If you want it to split from every line, you can use `string_name.split('\n')`. To insert a string with multiple lines, use a multi line string with three delimiters of your choice: `'''` or `"""`. For example:

```
'''
hello
there
'''
```